# How is back pressure handled when NGINX receives more requests than available PHP-FPM processes?

Tags: php

Suppose I'm using NGINX and PHP-FPM. If I have 20 PHP-FPM processes and I receive 100 simultaneous web requests,  what manages the queue for the remaining 80 requests?